# Go multi-stage build with stretch and alpine

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux, stretch, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to build from go stretch using -race and then copy it to the small alpine container to reduce final size. But I got this error during starting:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12.6-stretch as build-env
WORKDIR /goman/
ADD . .
RUN GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor  go test -race -v ./...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOBIN=/goman/apps/ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go install -v \
 -a -tags netgo -installsuffix netgo -mod vendor -ldflags "-d -s -w" ./cmd/...


FROM alpine:3.10
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates tzdata
COPY --from=build-env /goman/apps/ /apps
COPY --from=build-env /goman/conf /conf
WORKDIR /apps/
```

I can clearly see files when sh`ing in container and the permissions are correct

Comment: For which file or directory its giving the error?

Comment: @mchawre I use entrypoint /apps/my_executable and got this error

Comment: Whatever image is created out of this, just run a container out of it in bash shell `docker run -itd image bash` and then `docker exec -it container-id bash` and check if the file or dir exists.

Comment: @mchawre I sh'ed in container ls'ed the dir, all of my executables were there, and with right permissions, but it cannot execute them even with sh erroring with 'no such file or directory'

Comment: What system you are running it on? If you are running windows try to convert EOL from CRLF to LF at your .sh file

Comment: @ttomalak I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, EOL should not be a problem

Comment: You might want to try using golang:1.12-alpine for your first stage. Furthermore, I do not see a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` directive in your second stage.

Comment: In case it is a public repo, it could not hurt to add its URL to the question.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I need to use stretch because of -race flag, entrypoint is passed through docker-compose file, which worker when I used alpine builder, and I checked that executables exist inside container and right permissions is set.

Comment: You might have a rather different problem, namely libc. As far as I can see it, you have to decide wether to have the cake or eat it...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg what the problem might be? Any directions where to look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196715/discussion-between-markus-w-mahlberg-and-fom-max).

Comment: This error message can (confusingly) appear when dynamically loaded libraries are not present. Please use `ldd` to see the libraries you're executable requires. If it prints 'not a dynamic executable', everything is fine.

Comment: Exactly the same issue, but I compiled a C++ application, not a Go one. I have 2 Dockerfiles. The second one that attempts to run the binary in Alpine does not work. The first one, doing exactly the same, but in Debian only, works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `go build` instead of `go install`. In this case, I think, you only need to build an executable from the source, not install and build the remote one.